# MVC3 JSCOLOR values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jscolor

I am very new to MVC, and I am trying to get the value from  JScolor  in my view, but I am hitting a brick wall, and there doesnt seem to be any info out there, so how is it done?
I should add I am doing this in the view, and trying to update via EF4.1.

Comment: What do you want to do ? Can you elaborate some more. Like you have to send it to the controller or do changes on the same page(view).

Comment: I want to be able to send the selected color from the view to the controller, so that I can then save it to the database.

Comment: did you display a color picker in your MVC , view > could u tell me how did u do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a model in this view. You can simply write

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.selectedColor, new { @class = "Color" })
```

Where selectedColor is a property in the model

In the controller, you well get that model's property

Example Controller Code

```
 public ActionResult SaveColor(SelColor model){

 string myColor =  SelColor.selectedColor; 
 ...
 ..
 }
```

In the above code, SelColor is model's name
SaveColor is controller's Action

In the view, use Html.BeginForm() to call the desired controller's action.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, would be so much easier in normal webforms!.